# How can I create a 1D vector from a 2D vector in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have a 2D vector of size n x m and I want to create a 1D vector of size n with all the elements in column 0 of 2D vector, how can I achieve this with one line of code?

Basically, I want to minimize the 3 lines in the body of the function into 1 line.

```
vector<int> jimOrders(vector<vector<int>> orders) {
    vector<int> res;
    for (auto i:orders) res.push_back(i[1]);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Show how your "vectors" are declared.

Comment: You can write multiple statements into one line in C++, which makes your question pretty meaningless. For a start, implement a solution to show you made an effort yourself. Then, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah just saw that. He put the code now

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm new to competitive programming and trying to minimize the number of lines of code with obvious solutions. I thought there might be a function out there for it which I can't seems to find.

Comment: Well, if you now delete all linebreaks, there's your solution in one line.

Comment: I don't see how `for (auto &i:orders) {i[0] = i[1] + i[0]; i[1] = x ++;}` is at all related to the question you're asking. Please remove code that is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way:

- Create a new vector with a size equals to the original vector (only that this won't be a vector of vectors of int, just a vector of int).
- Then fill it with the contents of `v[row][0]`, `v` being the original vector.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/j93anobde)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // generate
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    std::vector<int> w(v.size());

    std::generate(std::begin(w), std::end(w), [row=0, &v]() mutable { return v[row++][0]; });

    for (auto&& i : w) { std::cout << i << " "; } std::cout << "\n";
}
```

In a bit more generic way, still using vector of vectors though:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/cG14Paz5M)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // generate
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
auto slice_column(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v, size_t col)
{
    std::vector<T> ret(v.size());
    std::generate(std::begin(ret), std::end(ret), [row=0, &v, &col]() mutable { return v[row++][col]; });
    return ret;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    auto w{ slice_column(v, 0) };
    for (auto&& i : w) { std::cout << i << " "; } std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `v.size()` is not enough for the second vector.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `w` will contain as many elements as each column in `v`, won't it? And that's exactly the numer of rows in `v`, i.e., `v.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a 1D vector of size n with all the elements in column 0 of 2D vector

This answer focuses on the above.

Create a view over the first element in each vector and return `{begin(), end()}` for that view to create the resulting `vector` from those iterators:

```
#include <ranges> // std::views::transform
#include <vector>

template<class T> 
std::vector<T> jimOrders(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& orders) {
    auto view = orders | std::views::transform([](const auto& i) { return i[0]; });
    return {view.begin(), view.end()};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aKjTGKGqM)